# Triple integral $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, alternative-proof, multiple-integral

The triple integral: 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{32}$$
can be confirmed using Mathematica.

But how can one show it by hand? I provide two answers below: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3303570/9464),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3303797/9464). Are there any other methods?

---

[**Context added later by Jack:**]

See also [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%282%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7Bz%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) calculation from Wolfram Alpha:

> [image]

[image]

---

[**Added later by OP:**]
The triple integral was fabricated by the method of the integral representation of  $1/p^2=\int_{0}^{\infty} t e^{pt} dt.$ See my first solution in the Answer below. The final result was confirmed numerically by Mathematica. More interestingly Mathematical gives this integral $I=\pi^2/12-A$ in analytic mode where A is Ahmed's Integral! which equals $5\pi^2/96$.

Comment: See also: [Evaluate $\int\int\int_{[0,1]^3}\frac{dxdydz}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2955676) - found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bdx%20dy%20dz%7D%7B(1%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2)%5E2%7D%24&p=1). Some tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)